# How can I print after each parameter is inputed in a method?

Tags: java, format

I know my problem but I can't seem to figure out a way to solve it.

What I want to do is after the user gives their preferred username, I want to print the phoneNumber next to it the input, and the problem I'm running into is this.

I would get the user to input,

Username: PhoneNumber: then now they can input

Instead what I want is something like this:

Username: input from the method parameter.....

phoneNumber: same thing as above

**UPDATED VERSION:**

This is the error I get

> userName cannot be resolved to a variable

```
 public void createCustomer(String userName) {
   
    System.out.print("Enter username: ");
    this.user = input.nextLine();
    this.user = userName;
    
    this.password = password;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.email = email;
}
  
public static void main (String args[]) {
    CustomerUI customer = new CustomerUI();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    if(shouldCreate() == true) {
        customer.createCustomer(userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to save the inputs in local variables and then pass those to the method later. that way you can insert whatever you want inbetween getting the input and calling the method.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense I thought about it, thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

You can scan each line after outputting the prompt to input the username or the phone number. For example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter username: ");
String username = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Username: " + username);
```

And then the same for phone number. You can then passed the values to the createCustomer method:

```
customer.createCustomer(username, phoneNumber, otherVar, anotherVar, lastVar);
```

Edit to address updated code: you are not defining username in the main method. If we go through your code, this is what is happening:

- We enter at the main method where you define customer (a CustomerUI object), and the input (a Scanner object).
- If the shouldCreate() method returns true, we will then create the customer using `customer.createCustomer(userName)`. However, at this point, the userName has not bee defined anywhere (e.g. `String userName;`)
- In createCustomer, we print out the line `"Enter username: "` to the console
- We then set the `user` class variable to the line entered in the console, suing `input.nextLine()`. However, at this point, we have no variable called `input` defined in this method. It was defined in `main`, but as a local variable. Therefore, it cannot be accessed in this other method.
- The `user` class variable is then assigned from the `userName` method parameter. This would overwrite the `input.nextLine()` value, rendering that line useless

What I would recommend:

- Put the `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` line into the createCustomer method
- Remove the parameters of the `createCustomer` method, and instead assign the values from the `input.nextLine()` method each time

Alternatively:

- Keep the `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` line in the main method
- Move the `input.nextLine()` method calls into the main method, and assigning their values to local variables
- Pass these variables to the `createCustomer` method which can then assign this to the class variables

Comment: Look at my post again, I Updated it and look at the bottom of "UPDATED VERSION"

Answer (score 0):

Instructions in a program are almost always executed in the order they are written (at lease within a method).

So what you do is first outputting the questions and later calling the input method. To change that you need to reorder the instructions.

problem is, that you directly pass the input return values to another method. So you have to introduce some *local variables* to store those return values until you pass them to the next method:

```
     System.out.print("");
    System.out.print("Username: ");
    String userName =input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("PhoneNumber: ");
    String phoneNumber =input.nextLine();
    customer.createCustomer(userName, phoneNumber,
          input.nextLine(),input.nextLine(),input.nextInt());
```